# How to set custom icon in Google Map Application from android Intent?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+destination1+"to:"+destination2));

startActivity(intent);
```

I implement this code right now and it is working fine for me. Now i need to add custom icon on that particular destination. How to achieve this? If this is not possible.

Then how to get same view like attached pictures in "SupportMapFragment".

Thanks

[need this type of view with start button in SupportMapFragment. How can i do this? Please check images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGXgR.png)

[Start button view like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLS64.png)

your ideas and help is appreciate

Comment: Anyone here? Please help me. Is it possible to set custom icon in gogle map application?

Comment: Which icon need to change? Please highlight that image.

Comment: need to change icon in white color with blue arrow on map(means current location icon).

Comment: u understand @AnkitaShah?

Comment: Do you want to change current location pin in google map app?

Comment: yes. i need to set custom icon.

Comment: is it possible? if this is not possible then Then how to get same view like attached pictures in "SupportMapFragment".

Comment: Maybe It is not possible. You have to use google APIs for same. For direction, google direction API is available.

Comment: I implement this with google Api and custom marker is working but i need same view as shown in attached file in "SupportMapFragment". is it possible? @AnkitaShah

Comment: Are you asking for direction right?

Comment: means i need same view. like in first image there is start button. then user press start button so navigation starts. and in image it shows time so i need that time to be shown in "SupportMapFragment". So i need that same view whic is shown in images in "SupportMapFragment". @AnkitaShah

Comment: Is it possible? please someone answer me